# Msmq Queue permission how to add a iss AppPool with powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, msmq

New-MsmqQueue -Name "ThisIsTestName" -QueueType Private create a Queue

**but** how do i add an application iis apppool to a MSMQ queue with Powershell

The manual way is add IIS AppPool\ThisIsTestName on Security fane

I only see guides that are about add user and set permission

\Lars Ole

Comment: Do you look for [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/new-webapppool?view=windowsserver2019-ps) ?

Comment: You have a [PowerShell snap-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-making-simple-configuration-changes-to-web-sites-and-application-pools) that can be used to add AppPool from a PowerShell script. I guess this is what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this manual process .......

Go to the application pool list in the IIS Management Console and note the application pool name for the desired application
Right-click on the MSMQ queue in Server Manager > Properties > Security
Click Add
Enter the object name IIS APPPOOL{application pool name from step 1}. This should auto-complete to the name of the application pool
Grant the required permissions - generally this will be Peek Message and/or Receive Message.

but how do i do it with powershell

Answer (score 0):

WebTestMSMQ is a apppool and billpay is a Queue name

**Get-MsmqQueue -Name "billpay" -QueueType Private | Set-MsmqQueueAcl -UserName "IIS AppPool\WebTestMSMQ" -Allow FullControl**

The Answer after run is
private$\billpay IIS APPPOOL\MSMQService  Allow  FullControl

it finds itself IIS APPPOOL